# My text data doesn't upload into python shell

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, text

I want to append all of text file string data into python shell's array by reading through all of text file and import into array as string data, but when I try to import all of data into arrays from text file I already put in, however This programmed code doesn't output all of text data from array and output nothing.
Can you find any programming errors from this code below? I already make ally of text file that code required read from.

```
    def set_up_time_arrive():
        ##First of all, we are going to append all of times BusA arrived from text file
        ##And We need also remove all of text data into array.
        BusA = Insert_bus_data_A()
        BusB = Insert_bus_data_B()
        BusC = Insert_bus_data_C() 
        BusD = Insert_bus_data_D()
        BusE = Insert_bus_data_E()
        BusF = Insert_bus_data_F()

        return BusA, BusB, BusC, BusD, BusE, BusF

    

    def Insert_bus_data_A():
        Fileinput = open("Bus_A.txt", "r") 
        if Fileinput == 'r':
            data = Fileinput.read()
            BusA.append(data)
        Fileinput.close()

        return BusA

    def Insert_bus_data_B():
        Fileinput = open("Bus_B.txt", "r") 
        if Fileinput == 'r':
            data = Fileinput.read()
            BusB.append(data)
        Fileinput.close()

        return BusB

    def Insert_bus_data_C():
        Fileinput = open("Bus_C.txt", "r") 
        if Fileinput == 'r':
            data = Fileinput.read()
            BusC.append(data)
        Fileinput.close()

        return BusC

    def Insert_bus_data_D():
        Fileinput = open("Bus_D.txt", "r") 
        if Fileinput == 'r':
            data = Fileinput.read()
            BusD.append(data)
        Fileinput.close()
    
        return BusD

    def Insert_bus_data_E():
        Fileinput = open("Bus_E.txt", "r") 
        if Fileinput == 'r':
            data = Fileinput.read()
            BusE.append(data)
        Fileinput.close()

        return BusE

     def Insert_bus_data_F():
        Fileinput = open("Bus_F.txt", "r") 
        if Fileinput == 'r':
            data = Fileinput.read()
            BusF.append(data)
        Fileinput.close()
 
        return BusF

    BusA, BusB, BusC, BusD, BusE, BusF = set_up_time_arrive()

    print(BusA)
    print(BusB)
    print(BusC)
    print(BusD)
    print(BusE)
    print(BusF)
```

Comment: None of those `Fileinput == 'r'` conditions can ever be true, as in each case `Fileinput` is an open file object, not a string.  What were you expecting these tests to do?

Comment: I was expected to this programs to import all of text fire into python array to output all of text data as contents of allay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to your description, you could use something like this

```
def Insert_bus_data(file_path):
    with open(file_path, "r") as fh:
        return fh.readlines()

BusA = Insert_bus_data('Bus_A.txt')
BusB = Insert_bus_data('Bus_B.txt')
BusC = Insert_bus_data('Bus_C.txt')
BusD = Insert_bus_data('Bus_D.txt')
BusE = Insert_bus_data('Bus_E.txt')
BusF = Insert_bus_data('Bus_F.txt')

print(BusA)
print(BusB)
print(BusC)
print(BusD)
print(BusE)
print(BusF)
```